# Do I have too many if statements on my theme.liquid file?

Tags: css, shopify, liquid

Here's my code in my theme.liquid file:

it tells my theme which css file to load if you land on that collection

```
  
  {% if template contains 'hammersusa' %}
      {{ 'hammersusa.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
{% else %}
       {{ 'shop.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
{% endif %}
  
  {% if template contains 'brakefailure' %}
      {{ 'brakefailure.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
{% else %}
       {{ 'shop.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
{% endif %}
  
  {% if template contains 'lotsofconcerns' %}
      {{ 'lotsofconcerns.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
{% else %}
       {{ 'shop.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
{% endif %}
  
  {% if template contains 'personalitems' %}
      {{ 'personalitems.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
{% else %}
       {{ 'shop.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
{% endif %}
      
  {% if template contains 'hammers1' %}
      {{ 'hammers1.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
{% else %}
       {{ 'shop.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
{% endif %}
  
  {% if template contains 'hitcinders' %}
      {{ 'hitcinders.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
{% else %}
       {{ 'shop.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
{% endif %}
```

my issue is when I want to change the entire body background color or the wrapper background color, it only allows me to do it on my last if statement for 'hitcinders.css' when I try to change the body background for say 'brakefailure.css' it loads the body background of my native shop.css file instead.

I tried to combine them into else if statements, and that gave me another issue.

Any suggesstions? The website is https://hammersusa.com

Again, https://hammersusa.com/collections/hit-cinders is correct and I'm trying to do that for the subsequent collections in the navigation.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i should have looked at the liquid syntax for else if. They so oddly use {% elsif %} instead...

THIS IS CORRECT:

```
      {{ 'hammersusa.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
  {% elsif template contains 'brakefailure' %}
      {{ 'brakefailure.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
  {% elsif template contains 'hitcinders' %}
      {{ 'hitcinders.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
  {% elsif template contains 'hammers1' %}
      {{ 'hammers1.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
  {% elsif template contains 'lotsofconcerns' %}
      {{ 'lotsofconcerns.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
  {% elsif template contains 'personalitems' %}
      {{ 'personalitems.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
{% else %}
       {{ 'shop.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
  
{% endif %}
```

Comment: If the css file name and template suffix are same, you can use a ````assign```` / ````capture````  functions and reduce it to a single ````if ... else````

Comment: How do you use assign and capture ?